# Lambda - como utilizar o operador || (OR) num .Any()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, expressões-lambda

Qual seria a forma correta de implementar a linha abaixo, em **Lambda**?

```
ListaDeRespostasPossiveis.Any(x => x.Nome == "respostaUm" || x.Nome == "respostaDois")
```

Vi alguns exemplos no Stack Overflow em inglês, mas não achei para o método `Any()`. E a maioria dá respostas para LINQ.

O código está num arquivo `.cshtml`, e eu queria manter a expressão Lambda em uma única linha. 
Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem o seu problema, mas o seu código funciona perfeitamente.

Note que quando você utiliza o [.any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) a sua resposta será um `bool`, ou seja, `true` ou `false`.

Se você está realizando isso como se fosse um filtro para uma lista, você receberá um erro mesmo.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
          var ListaDeRespostasPossiveis = new List<Resposta>(){
                new Resposta() { id = 1, Nome = "respostaUm"},
                new Resposta() { id = 2, Nome = "respostaDois"},
                new Resposta() { id = 3, Nome = "respostatres"},
                new Resposta() { id = 4, Nome = "respostaQuatro"}
            };


        bool resppostasFiltro = ListaDeRespostasPossiveis.Any(x => x.Nome == 
                                    "respostaUm" || x.Nome == "respostaDois");

        //Como existe a respostaUm ou RespostaDois, o resultado aqui será True
        Console.WriteLine(resppostasFiltro);
    }
}

public class Resposta{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Rodando o [exemplo acima no dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q518Hc) é possível ver que o resultado é `True`. Isso porque existe uma resposta com o `Nome == "respostaUm"`. Se você editar e remover o `respostaUm` e o `respostaDois` do exemplo, o resultado será `False`.

Agora, se você espera uma lista, utilize o [.Where()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) ao invés do `.Any()`.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Na verdade eu fiz a pergunta de forma conceitual, pois não achava exemplos para a mesma. Agora temos! Obrigado! PS: Fiz o teste, funciona como pensei mesmo!

Comment: Outra coisa é que você acabou diferenciando e explicando `.Where()` e `.Any()`, isso foi bem útil tb! Valeu!

Comment: Olá @ThiagoU.SperandioN., tudo bem? Então, pela sua pergunta eu supus que o problema era mais conceitual mesmo, e que poderia estar tendo algum tipo de confusão, por isso que adicionei ambos os exemplos em minha resposta. Fico feliz por ter ajudado